# Data parsing in object returned

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I am quite new to OOP, so this is probably a stupid question.

I have a Database abstraction layer class that like so:

```
class DB {
public static $instance = null;

private     $_pdo = null,
            $_query = null,
            $_error = false,
            $_results = null,
            $_count = 0;

private function __construct() {
    try {
        $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
    } catch(PDOExeption $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public static function getInstance() {
    // Already an instance of this? Return, if not, create.
    if(!isset(self::$instance)) {
        self::$instance = new DB();
    }
    return self::$instance;
}

public function query($sql, $params = array()) {

    $this->_error = false;

    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)) {
            foreach($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}




public function results() {
    // Return result object
    return $this->_results;
}



public function count() {
    // Return count
    return $this->_count;
}

public function error() {
    return $this->_error;
}
```

When I call the query method from another file

```
    $users = DB::getInstance()->query('SELECT * FROM users');
var_dump($users);
```

I get the users data in this format:

> DB Object ( [_pdo:DB:private] => PDO Object ( ) [_query:DB:private] => PDOStatement Object >( [queryString] => SELECT * FROM sheild ) [_error:DB:private] => [_results:DB:private] => >Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [sid] => 1 [name] => Scutum [weight] => 55 [defense] => 90 >[description] => Roman tower shield ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [sid] => 2 [name] => >Modified Scutum [weight] => 65 [defense] => 100 [description] => Modified heavier scutum >that provides more protection ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [sid] => 3 [name] => Round Parmula >[weight] => 30 [defense] => 60 [description] => smaller shield used by Thracian warrioirs ) >[3] => stdClass Object ( [sid] => 4 [name] => Rectangular Parmula [weight] => 40 [defense] >=> 75 [description] => Half the sized of Scutum ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [sid] => 5 >[name] => Hoplon [weight] => 20 [defense] => 35 [description] => The Hoplon is a small, >round bronze shield worn on the arm ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [sid] => 6 [name] => Aspis >[weight] => 35 [defense] => 50 [description] => Iron version of Hoplon ) ) >[_count:DB:private] => 6 )

Why would's this code work?

```
    foreach ($shields as $shield) {
    echo $sheild->name;
}
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Eeee because it's a object.

Comment: I think you should return $this->_results instead $this

Comment: Lol, I knew it was something like that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a results method, use it. I'm not sure you can iterate through a private object outside of class though.

```
$results = $users->results();
foreach($results as $shield){
    echo $user->name;
    //your code here
}
```

Or change the $this->_result from private to public in your DB Class

Comment: Yeah I used  $shields = DB::getInstance()->query('SELECT * FROM sheild')->results();

 foreach ($shields as $shield) {
  echo $shield->name;
 }    and it worked!